# How to separate the country code from a phone number?

Tags: javascript

I was having lots of phone numbers (e.g. 1-123-456-7890) in my DB. What I have to do is, separate the country dialing code (in this case 1 which is for US/Canada) from the phone number.

I tried creating a JSON list of all countries and when loading the page, I separated the phone number and country code. It was working fine till I got some numbers which start with `+` or having only 6 or 7 digits in the phone number (in which case there is no country code).

I have tried Google's GeoName API but it doesn't return what I was expecting. And I couldn't find any API for getting the country code from the phone number.

Comment: Why do you want to separate the country code from the phone number?

Comment: for the UI purpose, and I wanted to add country list with dialing codes for better UX

Comment: well, there is no easy answer for this case, I would go with catching country code with regex, but if you want some example I need all possible formats you want to operate on

Comment: I suspect you'll find this is more or less impossible. While you can tell that any number starting with a `+` will then have the international dialling code as the next digits, for any other number you won't be able to tell if it is a local number or an international number that is either missing the dialling prefix or has a country specific dialling prefix on it.

Comment: @Kejt — How would you write a regex that would match country codes?

Comment: If there is always a separator between the number and the country code, you can use RegEx to get all the numbers before the separator. In the example `1-123-456-7890`, there is the separator `-` between the country code and the number. See example here http://regexr.com/3gjfl

Comment: agreed @ChristianValentin but some numbers are **1234567890** which is the main issue for me. there is no consistency in the phone numbers.

Comment: then I would fix it with quantifier http://regexr.com/3gjfr

Comment: I tied that but the problem with this is when I have some numbers without country dialing code, it will still take first two digits as county code. eg **621234567** in this case county code is 62 which is Indonesia.'

Comment: then you can indicate by yourself, that when the length of number is bigger than 9 we have country code inside :) (with throwing all '-' out)

Answer (score 10):

This is one of the sort of problems which is quite complicated. I would suggest to use a library like [libphonenumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js).

I created a little helper function, that uses the US country code by default:

```js
function getCountryCode( input ) {
  // Set default country code to US if no real country code is specified
  const defaultCountryCode = input.substr( 0, 1 ) !== '+' ? 'US' : null;
  let formatted = new libphonenumber.asYouType( defaultCountryCode ).input( input );
  let countryCode = '';
  let withoutCountryCode = formatted;
  
  if ( defaultCountryCode === 'US' ) {
    countryCode = '+1';
    formatted = '+1 ' + formatted;
  }
  else {
    const parts = formatted.split( ' ' );
    countryCode = parts.length > 1 ? parts.shift() : '';
    withoutCountryCode = parts.join( ' ' );
  }
  
  return {
    formatted,
    withoutCountryCode,
    countryCode,
  }
}

console.log( getCountryCode( '1-123-456-7890' ) );
console.log( getCountryCode( '+12133734' ) );
console.log( getCountryCode( '+49300200100' ) );
console.log( getCountryCode( '621234567' ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/libphonenumber-js/0.4.27/libphonenumber-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for number like **621234567** it return *621234567* as country code

Comment: Yea I just realized it as well. I converted my little example to a more complex function. Now it returns an object which contains the formatted number and the country code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have a list of all countries with codes and then loop it and verify if the number starts with the code.

The problem with the libphonenumber-js is that it verifies the number with and without the country code, then sometimes there are more than one possibility for a number.

If you want to strictly find the code and the code is not omitted go with the code below.

```
  handleInternationalPhoneNumber(number){
    const possibleDDIs = [];

    allCountriesPhonCodes.forEach((country) => {
      if (number.startsWith(country.code)) {
        possibleDDIs.push(country);
      }
    });

    return possibleDDIs;
  }
```